# Can Snappy Ubuntu be installed on VirtualBox on Windows Host?

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-core

I am running VirtualBox on Windows host. I would like to test out Snappy Ubuntu on VirtualBox first. Can this be done? If yes, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely! Assuming you want amd64, download the Ubuntu Core image for it (release candidate [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/xenial/daily-preinstalled/current/ubuntu-core-16-amd64-rc.img.xz)), and uncompress it to get the raw image. Then convert it into a VDI for Virtualbox. In Ubuntu I do that like this (I assume this command is also available in Windows):

```
$ VBoxManage convertdd ubuntu-core-16-amd64-rc.img ubuntu-core-16-amd64-rc.vdi --format VDI
```

Now create a new machine, select the VDI as the hard drive image, and boot.

Comment: [rc2](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/xenial/daily-preinstalled/current/ubuntu-core-16-amd64-rc2.img.xz) now