# U Core hosted on OSX

Tags: virtualization, snap, macosx, ubuntu-core, golang

id like to start experimenting with snaps on ubuntu core.  Ideally start with a Docker image or Virtual Box container.  Eventually I want to remotely deploy goLang apps, on rasspi's... but I am confused on best strategies to get a dev system running on my Mac.   Should I switch to a windows machine?  any other strategies?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to inconveniently switch to a different machine. Ubuntu Core is so lightweight that you can easily run it as a guest OS in VirtualBox by [converting it into a VDI for VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/840050/can-snappy-ubuntu-be-installed-on-virtualbox-on-windows-host/840055#840055). Create a new VM, select the VDI as the hard drive image, and boot.